# Identity regarding coefficients of Legendre polynomials

Tags: polynomials, legendre-polynomials

In the book I am studying, the author says:

> Since $\phi_q$ is a polynomial of degree $q$, for all $j=1,2, \dots, l$, there exist real numbers $b_{qj}$ such that $$u^j=\sum_{q=0}^{j}b_{qj}\phi_q(u), \forall u\in[-1,1].$$

In this case, $\phi_q$ is actually a Legendre polynomial and the set of $\phi$'s  form a basis for the polynomials of degree at most $j$.

I think it is a strong result and I am not able to show it.

**How can I argue about the existence of such coefficients $b_{qj}$?**

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers It is just saying that when we have a set of polynomials such that deg$(p_k)=k$ for $k=0 \cdots n$, they constitute a basis of $\mathbb{R}_{\leq n}[x]$

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. In my case, $\phi_0,\dots,\phi_j$ indeed form an orthonormal basis for the polynomials of degree $\leq j$. Since $u^j$ is in this space, obviously it is a linear combination of the $\phi 's$. Maybe you write this as an answer, then I can vote it (if you care about the points to earn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this is saying is that the set $\{\phi_{0}, \phi_{1}, \ldots, \phi_{j}\}$ forms a basis for the vector space of (real) polynomials having degree at most $j$ (for each $0 \leq j \leq l$). Thus the polynomial $x^{j}$ is a linear combination of these polynomials (i.e. the coefficients $b_{qj}$ in question exist).

It is worded a little strangely to say that the equality holds for all $u \in [-1,1]$; really it will hold for all $u \in \mathbb{R}$, since these polynomials are equal everywhere.

Comment: The interval $[-1,1]$ is associated with the fact that Legendre polynomials are orthogonal in $L^2([-1,1])$. This is just a detail though. You've answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Write things in terms of matrices:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_0(u)\\\phi_1(u)\\\phi_2(u)\\\vdots\\\phi_l(u)
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{0,0}&0&0&\cdots&0\\
a_{0,1}&a_{1,1}&0&\cdots&0\\
a_{0,2}&a_{1,2}&a_{2,2}&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{0,l}&a_{1,l}&a_{2,l}&\cdots&a_{l,l}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u^0\\u^1\\u^2\\\vdots\\u^l
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since $\phi_j$ has degree $j$, $a_{j,j}\ne0$. The determinant of a lower triangular matrix is
$$
\prod_{j=0}^la_{j,j}\ne0
$$
Thus, we can invert the lower triangular matrix to get a lower triangular matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{0,0}&0&0&\cdots&0\\
b_{0,1}&b_{1,1}&0&\cdots&0\\
b_{0,2}&b_{1,2}&b_{2,2}&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
b_{0,l}&b_{1,l}&b_{2,l}&\cdots&b_{l,l}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi_0(u)\\\phi_1(u)\\\phi_2(u)\\\vdots\\\phi_l(u)
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
u^0\\u^1\\u^2\\\vdots\\u^l
\end{bmatrix}
$$